# Previous view unresponsive when touchUpInside Back button with [self.view removeFromSuperview]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am new to iPhone Programming.

Basically I have a MFSideMenuViewController with settings viewController as rightSideViewController.

Settings ViewController is with UITableView and when I tap at any Index of tableview its loading another VC as `[rootViewController.view addSubView:VC];` with implemented back button code - `[self.view removeFromSuperview];` until now its working fine

```
SettingsVC.h
//UITableView Delegate method
if(indexPath.row==1){
VC=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vcStoryBoardIdentifier"];
[VC.view setFrame:[[APP_DELEGATE window] frame]];
[[[[APP_DELEGATE window] rootViewController] view] addSubview:VC.view];
}
```

In this VC I have a tableview. when I tap at any `index path.row` it is loading another VC named anotherVC as subview to VC `[VC.view addSubView:anotherVC];`

```
    VC.m
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTblPS) name:@"VCTblReload" object:nil];
        }

-(void)reloadTblPS{
   [VCTableView reloadData];
}

    //UITableview DataSource method
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
                static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
                    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                    if(cell == nil)
                    {
                        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                     if(indexPath.row == 0)
                        {
                button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                [button setImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button setImage:img2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                [button setFrame:CGRectMake(220,10,60,20)];
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(openAnotherVc:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                            [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
                }
                }
                return cell;

                }
    -(void)openAnotherVc:(id)sender{

            anotherVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"anotherVCStoryBoardID"];
                    [[anotherVC view] setFrame:[[APP_DELEGATE window] frame]];
                    [self.view addSubview:[anotherVC view]];

            }
    -(IBAction)VCcancelBtn:(id)sender{
                [self.view removeFromSuperview];
            //working fine
            }
```

this anotherVC also containing a Cancel button with `[anotherVC.view removeFromSuperView];

```
anotherVC.m
-(IBAction)anotherVCcancelBtn:(id)sender{
  [self.view removeFromSuperView];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"VCTblReload" object:nil];
}
```

My problems are 2 here
**1. When I click on cancel button of anotherVC it is going to VC screen but the VC is unresponsive**
**2. the tableView present in VC is not reloading even I have used notifications and `[tableView reloadData];`**

*It would be great with explanation for your answer Thank you*

Comment: Can you post your code. not exactly getting your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer for my question is**

```
SettingsVC.h
//UITableView Delegate method
if(indexPath.row==1){
VC=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vcStoryBoardIdentifier"];
[VC.view setFrame:[[APP_DELEGATE window] frame]];
[[[[APP_DELEGATE window] rootViewController] view] addSubview:VC.view];
//[[self presentViewController:VC animated:NO completion:nil];
}


 VC.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTblPS) name:@"VCTblReload" object:nil];
        }

-(void)reloadTblPS{
   [VCTableView reloadData];
}

    //UITableview DataSource method
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
                static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
                    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                    if(cell == nil)
                    {
                        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                     if(indexPath.row == 0)
                        {
                button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                [button setImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button setImage:img2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                [button setFrame:CGRectMake(220,10,60,20)];
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(openAnotherVc:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                            [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
                }
                }
                return cell;

                }
-(void)openAnotherVc:(id)sender{

            anotherVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"anotherVCStoryBoardID"];
                    [[anotherVC view] setFrame:[[APP_DELEGATE window] frame]];
                    [[self presentViewController:anotherVC animated:NO completion:nil];]

            }
-(IBAction)VCcancelBtn:(id)sender{
                [self.view removeFromSuperview];
//[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
            //working fine
            }


anotherVC.m
-(IBAction)anotherVCcancelBtn:(id)sender{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"VCTblReload" object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
 if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        ContactUsVC *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContactUsVC"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
```

and in this method also

```
-(void)openAnotherVc:(id)sender
{

            UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            ContactUsVC *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContactUsVC"];
            [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
        }
```

Comment: Its not working. It gives a blank white screen instead of previous screen (VC)

Comment: have you written (yoursubviewVC).subviews instead of self.view.subviews i.e yoursubviewVC is the vc which you want to hide

Comment: the screen is getting for [self.view removeFromSuperview];. thats very cool., But the VC view is unresponsive or uninteractive. Thats what my problem

Comment: still your answer is not solving my problem

Comment: I tried in different way to solve the issues... little bit its working fine.. thank you @Aayush Katiyar

Comment: Your answer is not exactly right.. since when I press back button it showed black blank screen

Answer (score 0):

Use `Navigation Controller` to do this kind of stuff. then `Push` Viewcontroller instead of add to window and `pop` Viewcontroller instead of remove. add and remove are good practise for `UIView`. when it's comes to Viewcontrollers then you should use `NavigationController` to manage navigation stack. it will resolve your all issue i think. hope this will help.:)

Update :
And if you are using storyboard then you can use segue also. it make whole flow little bit easier. google it that how to use navigation controller with storyboard.

Comment: But in my project I am not using any segues and navigation controllers.. I did my self with different scenario.. some what its working right now.. thank you @lion

Comment: Use navigation controller. is this anything like this that you forcefully can't use ?

Comment: Yes it is.. Because the data is coming from Service.. according to the data the settings view controller is loading. so that I can't use here navigation controller